# How is 1 encoded in C/C++ as a float (assuming IEEE 754 single precision representation)?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

My impression is that C float has 8 bits of exponent and 23 bits of mantissa.

So one is 0011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 = 0x3F800000.

However, the following code produced 1.06535e+09  instead of 1. 
Can anyone help me understand why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>  

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float i = 0x3F800000;
    cout<<i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not assigning that bit pattern to `i`, but that particular integer.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you think `0011 1111 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 000` or `0x3F800000` should be equal to 1. Can you explain the thought process behind this?

Comment: Isnt that the standard IEEE representation? See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Although I haven't used C in years, I always believed that the specific representation of `float` and `double` depends on the target architecture, not on the C standard. Is my impression incorrect?

Comment: @EricJ.  looks like so. it is casting the hex to unsigned int and casting the unsigned int to float. How do I directly assign hex to float?

Comment: Please not 0x3f800000 is the IEEE 754 single precision representation of 1.0 only. C can be used on systems that do not support IEEE 754 (though such systems are probably rare), and furthermore, there's no guarantee the type `float` is 32-bits. You can use `uint32_t` from `<cstdint>` at least.

Comment: The question mentions C but shows C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is 1 coded in C as a float?
>
> Can anyone help me understand why (code fails)?

```
float i = 0x3F800000;
```

is the same as `i = 1065353216`;

---

In C, to overlay the bit pattern use a `union` or use `memcpy()`.

In C++, suggest `memcpy()`.

Using a cast risks failure due to anti-aliasing. [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56710780/how-is-1-coded-in-c-as-a-float#comment99985489_56710855)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

_Static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "Unexpected types");

int main(void) {
  union {
    uint32_t u; 
    float f;
  } x = {.u = 0x3f800000};
  float f = x.f;
  printf("%e\n", f);
  return 0;
}
```

On less common systems, this can fail due to

- `float` is not [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).
- Endian differs between `float/uint32`

Answer (score 1):

Using IEEE-754, the floating point number 1 is written as:

```
0 01111111 00000000000000000000000 (base-2) = 3f80 0000 (base-16)
```

So, your assumption is correct. Unfortunately, the bit-pattern represented by `0x3f800000` cannot be assigned to a float by just doing:

```
float a = 0x3f800000
```

The hexadecimal number will first be converted to an unsigned integer which has the value `1065353216` in base-10. This number will then implicitly be converted to the nearest floating-point number.

So in short, while your bit-pattern for an IEEE-754 floating point number is correct, your assumption how to assign this pattern is incorrect. Have a look at [Convert a hexadecimal to a float and viceversa in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323099/convert-a-hexadecimal-to-a-float-and-viceversa-in-c) how this can be achieved or the other answers in this question.